# Qt creator 4.11, create a link in the application output panel

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

I desesperatly try to find a way to make the application output panel a bit more useful by printing an error with a file path and a line number (basically _ *FILE* _ and _ *LINE* _ macros) and make it clickable from the pannel to go directly in the source file in the IDE.

Is it possible to do so with std::cout only ?

I found a post on stack which doesn't work with my need.

Comment: I don't get what you are asking from what you posted. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: When the application is running the standard output are printed into a specific pannel in qt-creator (application output). I want to make an error like "blahblah failed (/path/to/file:24)" and make it clickable. I'm pretty sure it's possible to achieve this, because Qt framework does it, but I wonder how we can trigger this feature with a simple printf() or std::cout by a specific syntax or something.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanic you need to use here is ANSI escape sequences.

ANSI escape sequences are processed by (mostly) Unix terminals and terminal emulators for changing the terminal behavior, e.g. formatting or coloring text. More recently, hyperlinks may be embedded using an escape sequence as well. For example, the `ls` utility may embed `file://` scheme links with the printed filenames and a terminal may allow to open a file by clicking on it. And GCC does this as well (see `-fdiagnostics-urls` option).

Several IDEs nowadays also support these links in their output panes. To form a link you need to print one escape sequence before the text and one after (to reset the link state), like so:

```
printf '\e]8;;http://example.com\e\\This is a link\e]8;;\e\\\n'
```

Note that `\e` is ESC, the other characters in the example are regular characters as printed.
Find a good documentation about this, esp. about how to form appropriate `file://` URIs [here](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda#file-uris-and-the-hostname).

Comment: Thanks you, I will dig this way !

Comment: Let us now when you have any results :)

Answer (score 1):

For Qt Creator to recognize a link to a source file in the Application Output, it needs to be in a specific format. In my tests I've found the following to work:

```
std::cout << "file:///home/user/project/src/foo.cpp:1234" << std::endl;
```

This follows the pattern `file://%{file}:%{line}`.

Since this question is related to Qt, you may want to set the `QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN` environment variable such that the file and line number is automatically included in your debug messages. For example:

```
QT_MESSAGE_PATTERN="%{message} (file://%{file}:%{line})"
```

For more information, see:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qSetMessagePattern
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html#warning-and-debugging-messages

Comment: This doesn't work with std::cout, the application output panel do not highlight the filepath. I'm not working with the Qt framework, I'm only using QtCreator as a standard C++ IDE. I'm pretty sure there is some additional data set by QXXX() to trigger the panel.

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans I just tested both std::cout and std::cerr and it's working fine for me (`std::cout << "file:///home/user/project/src/foo.cpp:1234" << std::endl;`, for example).